# Check list Box in C#

Tags: c#

I have written program below with checkbox. which works fine. but i want to write it in one checklistbox but don't know how to check 1st checklistbox is checked or 2nd.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
                MessageBox.Show("CheckBox1 is checked");
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
                MessageBox.Show("CheckBox2 is checked");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:it is a windows form application.

Comment: Could we get some more code of your actual program please?

Comment: Did you [search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items(v=vs.100).aspx)? Looks like what you need.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi:edited the post.

Comment: @JordyV:edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    /* iterate over all checked items from the checkedlistbox */
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT:** if you want to perform some operations based on the selected item
Try This:

```
foreach (int item in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case 0:/*first item selected here do something*/
            MessageBox.Show("1st item selected");
            break;

        case 1:/*first item selected here do something*/
            MessageBox.Show("2nd item selected");
            break;

        case 2:/*first item selected here do something*/
            MessageBox.Show("3rd item selected");
            break;
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

From MSDN: [`CheckedListBox.CheckedIndices Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Collection of checked indexes in this CheckedListBox.
>
> The collection of checked indexes is a subset of the indexes into the
>   collection of all items in the CheckedListBox control

`SelectedIndices` returns you the `selectedindex` values from the `Checkedlistbox`.
for example if there are 10 items in `checkedlistbox` and if you select item 1,item5 and item7 then it returns their respective `index` values(index always start with 0).

so it returns 0,4,6.

Comment: it was good, but what if my checkBox's name is different to the message that i want to show. your message box shows only content of check box.

Comment: @Riddle: you want to get the name of the checkbox?

Comment: No, i want like this, for example if i checked 1st one, do something. if checked 2nd one do something else.

Comment: @Riddle: how many items willbe there in your `checkedlistbox`?

Comment: @Riddle: check my eidted answer

Comment: more than 10 but in this example only 2 for making the code smaller.

Comment: :great, just would you mind explain about CheckedIndices, i'm not familiar with it.